# Stand alone executable generation

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I would like to create a stand alone executable for a Qt based visual c++ project. I have compressed the executable file in the debug directory and the dependencies together. I tried to start this application in another computer which doesn't has Qt. But it results in error, saying "cannot find Qtcore4.dll" even though it is available in the compressed file.

What is the other possible way to create the stand alone executable?

Comment: What do you mean by "compressed the executable file in the debug directory and the dependencies together?" Do you mean you built them statically, so they are one file? Or just that you put them in a zip archive or something?

Comment: Also, if you got the output from the "debug" directory, it is curious that it is asking for Qtcore4.dll. Are you sure it's not looking for something like Qtcore4d.dll? (Note the "d" in the library name.) I'm not on a Windows machine right now to get the exact name, but you have to match the correct version of the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

To create a standalone executable which does not require to have Qt4 installed, you have to compile your application statically. In your project options, in Visual Studio, there should be an option that would allow you to actually do just that. If you don't link statically, which is generally the default behavior, the executable tries to get the Qt library installed in the OS.

Note that your executable will be much larger as you will embed important part of the Qt library.